# Prevent user from jumping in mid-air

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to prevent a sprite from jumping again in mid-air. However, the way I'm implementing it is wrong, and I'm really lost.

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   CCActionJumpBy *jump_up = [CCActionJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0, 100) height:50 jumps:1];
   [player runAction:jump_up];
   CCActionJumpBy *come_down = [CCActionJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0, -100) height:50 jumps:1];
  [player runAction:come_down];

}

-(void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CCActionDelay *delay = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:2.0];
    [player runAction:delay];
}
```

From my understanding, the delay should prevent users from jumping again. Any tips? I'm sorry, I'm new to objective-c.

Comment: you probably want to check that your user is touching the ground, or has a vertical acceleration of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a CCActionDelay is useful to create a pause in a sequence of actions, not really useful in this context. Instead, i would manage the 'jumping' state in touch began, and not worry about touchEnded, as this.

you will need a property to control this state:

@property(nonatomic,readwrite)    BOOL isPlayerJumping;

and change touchBegan as follow:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if (!self.isPlayerJumping) {
       CCActionJumpBy *jump_up = [CCActionJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0, 100) height:50 jumps:1];
       CCActionJumpBy *come_down = [CCActionJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0, -100) height:50 jumps:1];
       CCActionCallBlock *end_jump = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
          self.isPlayerJumping = NO;
       }];
       CCActionbSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actions:jump_up,come_down,end_jump,nil];
       [player runAction:seq];
       self.isPlayerJumping = YES;
    }
}
```

}

obcit : not compiled, tested, just for the idea of it. There is more than one way to do this :)

Comment: compiled it and tested it! It works! 95% lol. for some reason, when the sprite jumps up its position, it does some sort of mini jump before it comes down. D:

Comment: oh, i was not paying attention . Although i dont use them, i think CCActionJumpBy is already an up-down motion. Try CCActionMoveBy instead. And, if the solution prevents 'jumping while jumping', it is the answer you were looking for :)

Comment: thanks @YvesLeborg :) everything works great now! i still managed to keep the CCActionJumpBy, I just made the come_down function have 0 jumps to stop the random motion.

Comment: then you can thank me by accepting the answer :) ... good luck with your app.